# Section of a divisor on a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C_1$ be a smooth plane conic and $C_2$ be a smooth plane cubic in $\mathbb P^3$ such that they lie in two different planes and $C_1, C_2$ intersects only at $1$ point (transversally). Moreover, assume that, there exists a smooth quintic surface $X$ in $\mathbb P^3$ which contains both $C_1$ and $C_2$. Let $C:=C_1+C_2$. If $H$ is a smooth hyperplane section of $X$, then is there a way to see that $h^0(\mathcal O_X(2H-C)) >0$?

I am not sure if structure exact sequence of curves on surfaces help here (because $C$ need not be necessarily smooth right?). Is there a more natural way (using the hypothesis) to see this?

Any argument is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that both $H-C_i$ are effective using the hypothesis?

Comment: @Mohan, I was also thinking along the same lines. Taking structure exact sequence for  $H \to X$ does not give anything useful. I also attempted Riemann-Roch, that also does not work. Perhaps the planes used in the construction plays a role here (which I'm unable to make precise). Could you please hint exactly how  are these becoming effective?

Comment: Take $H$ to be the plane containing $C_1$. Then $H\cap X=C_1+D_1$. So, $H-C_1=D_1$ is effective. Similarly $H-C_2$ is effective and thus $2H-C_1-C_2$ is effective.

Comment: @Mohan, thanks! again I was here, but my confusion was about two things, if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are two distinct planes used in the construction, then are we using the fact that after intersecting with $X$, as a hyperplane section, they are equivalent? Also in this case the hyperplane section is not irreducible ( Please let me know if these are not quite correct)

Comment: When you write $2H-C$, you are really talking about linear equivalence.